# Changing div content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code, I want to modify `#spock` content using jQuery :

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.href,
    server = "Testing123",
    content = "",
    background = "";
    content = '<p class="server-message ' + server + '">You are on the <strong>' + server + '</strong> server</p>';
    alert('content = ' + content);
    $("#spock").text(content);
});
</script>
<div id="#spock"></div>
```

I expect it to display "Testing123" on my page, yet I see nothing.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `id="#spock"` is not correct, you should rather use `id="spock"`. jQuery uses css syntext for selector (i.e. #spock)

Comment: I hate it when the answer is so simple you can't see it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the `id` of the element doesn't need the `#` in it:

```
<div id="spock"></div>
```

Secondly, you're adding HTML to the element so using `text()` will encode any HTML tags in the string. Use the `html()` function instead:

```
$("#spock").html(content);
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gs4cjn1a/)

Comment: That was it.  I hate it when the answer is so simple you can't see it.  Thanks!